Extending contour integral result to branch point
The PDF of the chi-squared distribution can be written as the Fourier inversion of its characteristic function:
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-itx}}{(1-2it)^{k/2}} dt$$
If we consider $k$ to be even, the pole at $-i/2$ is of integer order. We can then integrate over a semi-circular contour that encloses the pole and use Cauchy's integral formula to show that $f(x) \sim x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}$.
For odd $k$, we cannot use this derivation because then the singularity is a branch point. Yet we know that the same answer $f(x)$ holds.
What would be a way to extend the contour-integral derivation to the case of odd $k$? I am new to branch points and how to handle them, so an answer with explanatory steps will be helpful.

An interesting question :)
Let' consider
$$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-itx}}{(t+i)^\alpha}dt$$
To provide convergence we imply the condition $\alpha>0$. At integer $\alpha$ the integral can be evaluated by means of complex integration (closing the contour in the lower half plane and taking the residue at $t=-i$)
Let' consider the case of non-integer $\alpha$. We go in the complex plane and draw the cut from $-i$ to $-i\infty$ - to make the integrand a single-valued function in the low half-plane. Then we close the contour, going (clockwise) along the following contour $C$: the big arch of the radius $R\to\infty$, then the right bank of the cut (from $-iR$ to $-i-ir$), then clockwise around $z=-i$ - along the small circle of the radius $r\to0$, then along the left bank of the cut (from $-i-ir$ to $-iR$), and then along the big arch to the starting point. As we do not have singularities inside the contour,
$$g(x)=-\int_C\frac{e^{-izx}}{(z+i)^\alpha}dz$$
Integral along big arches tend to zero as $R\to\infty$. Making the substitution $z\to -i+z$ and using the fact that we go clockwise around the branch point
$$g(x)=-e^{-x}\left((1-e^{-2\pi i})\int_{-i\infty}^{-ir}\frac{dz}{z^\alpha}+\int_{C_r}\right)$$
where we denoted $I_{C_r}$ the integral along the small circle around $z=0$. As $z=-it=e^{-\frac{\pi i}2}t; t\in[r;\infty)$
$$g(x)=e^{-x}\left(e^{\frac{\pi i(\alpha-1)}2}(1-e^{-2\pi i\alpha})\int_r^\infty e^{-tx}t^{-\alpha}dt-\int_{C_r}\right)$$
It is straightforward to check that $g(x)$ is regular for all $\alpha>0$; it also follows from the fact that the initial integral is regular at $\alpha>0$. In the case $\alpha\in(0,1)$ we can take the limit $r\to0$: integral along the small circle vanishes, and we are left with
$$g(x)=e^{-x}e^{\frac{\pi i(\alpha-1)}2}(1-e^{-2\pi i\alpha})\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}t^{-\alpha}dt$$
$$=e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{\pi i(\alpha-1)}2}(1-e^{-2\pi i\alpha})\Gamma(1-\alpha)=2\pi ie^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi i(\alpha+1)}2}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\,\alpha\in(0,1)$$
According to the principle of analytical continuation we have to conclude that
$$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-itx}}{(t+i)^\alpha}dt=2\pi e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi i\alpha}2}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,\,\text{for all}\,\,\alpha>0$$
Coming back to your initial integral
$$f(x)= \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-itx}}{(1-2it)^{k/2}} dt=\frac1{4\pi}e^{\frac{\pi ik}4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{isx}2}}{(s+i)^{k/2}}ds=\frac{e^{-x/2}x^{k/2-1}}{2^{k/2}\Gamma\big(k/2\big)}, k>0$$
